# How to display the list of followers on the profile of all users

Tags: reactjs

I try to display the list of followers and followings on the profile of the users using their id, when I implement there is only the list of followers and followings of the current user that is connected, even if I follow the profile of another user
My Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Modal from "../Components/Log/Modals";
import { isEmpty } from "../Components/Utils";
import FollowHandler from "./FollowHandler";

const FollowingPopup = ({ followerId, type }) => {
    const userData = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer);
    const [Opening, setOpening] = useState(false);
    const { id: userId } = useParams();

    const [followingsPopup, setFollowingsPopup] = useState(false);



    const usersData = useSelector((state) => state.usersReducer);




    return (
        <Modal open={!Opening} onClick={() => setOpening(Opening)}>
            <span
                onClick={() => setOpening(!Opening)}
                className="followers__modal__close"
            ></span>
            <header className="followers__modal__header">
                <button
                    className="followers active-followers"
                >
                    Mes Abonnements
                </button>
            </header>

            {/**Les personnes suivis par l'utilsateur */}
            {!followingsPopup && (
                <>
                    <div className="followers__modal__content">
                        <ul>

                            {userId ? (usersData.map((user) => {

                                let follower = user.follower.map((users) => users.followerId)
                                for (let i = 0; i < usersData.length; i++) {

                                    if (user.id !== userId && follower.includes(user.id)) {
                                        return (
                                            <li key={user.id} className="followers__modal__followers">
                                                <a
                                                    href={`/${user.id}`}
                                                    className="followers__modal__followers__links"
                                                >
                                                    <img src={user.picture} alt="" />
                                                    <h4>{user.firstname + " " + user.lastname} </h4>
                                                </a>
                                                {user.id !== userData.id ? < FollowHandler followerId={user.id} type={'suggestion'} /> : null}
                                            </li>
                                        );
                                    }
                                }

                                return null;
                            })) : null}


                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}{" "}
            {/**Les personnes abonnés à l'utilsateur */}

        </Modal>
    );
};

export default FollowingPopup;
```

this code works perfectly and I manage to display the list of followers of current user who is logged in but when I click on the profile of another user, the same list of followers of the user who is logged in is displayed too, not the selected profile

[image: Data of followers]
[[image: Data of followings2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is unnecessary there.
This might be working for you but without a sandbox to test it's hard to tell.

```
const userFollowers =usersData.find(user=>user.id===userId).followers.map(follower=>follower.id);
usersData.map(user=>{
 if(userFollowers.includes(user.id)){
return (
    <li key={user.id} className="followers__modal__followers">
                                                <a
                                                    href={`/${user.id}`}
                                                    className="followers__modal__followers__links"
                                                >
                                                    <img src={user.picture} alt="" />
                                                    <h4>{user.firstname + " " + user.lastname} </h4>
                                                </a>
                                                {user.id !== userData.id ? < FollowHandler followerId={user.id} type={'suggestion'} /> : null}
                                            </li>
)
})
```

Comment: Exactly I get the data via the usersReducer but I thought that since I use useParams to get the user id and display according to the selected id that it will update the list of followers also in the same way as for the user information what advice can you give me to solve this problem?

Comment: @OumarMAURET inside the follower.includes I think you should pass userId instead of user.id, but it's hard to tell without seeing the actual data. The naming is also terrible tho.

Comment: I have already tried this approach but no data is loaded

Comment: I just added the screenshots of the followers and followings data

Comment: @OumarMAURET updated the answer see if that fits

Comment: It's great your answer helped me to solve the problem I made some changes on your answer and it works great now. Thank you mery much @Tony